# PHP function call and array passing in Javascript code

Tags: php, javascript, call

Pls help..

I have a dynamic form in which the no. of elements are not fixed, and i need to perform JS validation on the form. I have a PHP function that will return me an array of all elements that are currently displayed in form. I want to use this in the JS code..

I am trying something lyk dis::

```
function checkValidation() {

  <?php echo  
    // php function call
    $arrColumnsInfo = $this->fetch_fields_info();
    print('<pre>');
    print_r($arrColumnsInfo);
    print('</pre>');
  ?>
}
```

Not working for me..throws JS error..
OR this..

```
function checkValidation() {
  <?php=
    // php function call 
    $arrColumnsInfo = $this->fetch_fields_info();?>
    alert(<?=$arrColumnsInfo?>);
}
```

Again.. not working..

My PHP array output:

```
Array
(
[client_code] => Client Code::1::Basic company Info::desc::TB
[entity_name] => Entity Name::1::Basic company Info::::TB
[type_of_entity] => Type of entity::1::Basic company Info::Type of entity,Sole trader,Partnership,Australian Private Company, other::DD
[fixed_fees] => fixed fees::8::Fees Related::yes,no::RD
[billing_time] => Billing time::8::Fees Related::Weekly,Fortnightly,Monthly,Yearly::DD
)
```

The key here used is the name of form element.. 
eg. i am building my form lyk dis..

```
<input type="text" name="client_code" value="">...
```

and so on.. and in the same way all form elements are dynamically created. And now i want to validate this form so i again need this array in javascript.

Comment: defining array in js is slightly different then PHP..

Comment: but there must be a possibility to access PHP array in JS code.

Comment: You need to validate each of your dynamically generated elements before the form submits ??

Comment: Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php unless you simply add required to each field that needs to be validated and have JavaScript look for that

Comment: How does the dynamic field look like ?

Comment: yes... ubercooluk.. that is just a simple form validation on form submit. I have posted my dynamic field.. have a luk.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [json_encode](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to transform your PHP Array into a from that can be used by JavaScript.

```php
function checkValidation() {
  var data = <?php echo json_encode($this->fetch_fields_info()) ?>;
  // ... run your client-side checks
  alert(data);
}
```

Just keep in mind, that you always have to provide valid JavaScript code.
That can sometimes be quite tricky if you insist on writing that JavaScript code with inline PHP.

You should at least consider doing your validation on the server-side (in PHP) and only passing the result to your client.

Comment: hey.. i tried wd ur code. 
it does not works for me. when i alert(data) it gives me empty result.

Comment: try   var data = '<?php echo json_encode($this->fetch_fields_info()) ?>';

Answer (score 0):

your php code have to generate the result something like this:

```
var arr = <?php echo $arr; // result: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] ?>
```

or the other `array()` format that support in JavaScript..

it is just an example.

take a look on the give link : [Array in Javascript](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays)  this link tells you that what format you need to use an Array.

Answer (score -2):

data is not sufficient to help you @disha. please provide some more and edit  this .
also what is this '=' in you first line of php? provide some more details that someone can really help you.
Happy coding!

Comment: This must be a comment ..not even near to an answer

Comment: i am just trying it in a way.. i need to call this PHP function. so trying something like dis..